# Execute Windows scripts from a remote Rundeck server

Tags: shell, tomcat, cygwin, rundeck

I installed the Rundeck server in one Linux machine.

Tomcat is running in a Windows 7 machine.

Now, I want to stop and start the Tomcat service in the Windows machine by creating a job in Rundeck (on the Linux machine).

Is it possible?

Comment: Note that [Rundeck can be installed on Windows](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/installation.html) if this is primarily what you are supporting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

Install Cygwin, including openssh-server to the Windows machine. Generate a public key for the Rundeck server user and add it to the `.authorized_hosts` file on the Windows machine. Ensure you have port `22` or an alternate port accessible for SSH.

In rundeck, create a new job which fires the Tomcat executable or any commands you prefer for starting/stopping the service.

It may help to prefix the Rundeck job command with some `$PATH` variables if the connecting user account has trouble locating executables in the Windows/Cygwin environment.